# How to detect active network interface automatically

Tags: networking

I am using Ubuntu 15.10.

Many motherboards now ship with 2 network interfaces.  And rather common situation is when I have only one network cable plugged.
I do not want to hardcode MAC address into `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` by hand (imagine I have a lot of servers).

I want to detect automatically at boot time which interface has a link, and assign an address on that interface.

This will also allow me to change motherboard (in case of a failure), and after reboot with new MB network will be automatically configured, despite of MAC addresses change.

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can just parse the network interface with

```
ip link show |grep UP
```

And even append a "|grep eth" or whatever your network cards prefix is, to tighten the filter.

Comment: "ip link show | awk '/UP / {print $2}'" would show the name of the interface :-) Just for sake of completion...

Comment: if I do "ifconfig eth0 down", ip link show will not include "UP": eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST>, thought the cable still plugged.  So it is not the robust method to detect which interface has a link.

Answer (score 3):

Although it might be tempting achieving it through a script, why would you even try something like this when you can just bond both interfaces in a mode that suits you best, assign them a custom MAC-Address and let them work as if they were only one interface?

As interface bonding can avoid taking Physical Interface's MAC into account, in case of a MB failure your custom MAC-Adress would equally persist.

More information? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding

Regards

NOTE: Would have been a comment if I could do that :-)